# Making Sylius ProductImage translatable

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, sylius

I am gettin' mad making the Sylius ProductImage translatable. I need a ProductImage name and slug for SEO purposes.

What I've already done is:

- Override ProductIamge via param: sylius.model.product_image.class
- Added TranslatableInterface and required functionality to it
- Added ProductImageTranslation entity
- Added mapping file for ProductImage.orm.yml & ProductImageTranslation.orm.yml
- Extended config.yml

ProductImage.orm.yml

```
AppBundle\Entity\ProductImage:
    type: entity
    table: sylius_product_image
```

ProductImageTranslation.orm.yml

```
AppBundle\Entity\ProductImageTranslation:
    type: entity
    table: app_product_image_translation
    id:
        id:
          type: integer
          generator:
        strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        name:
            type: string
            nullable: true
        slug:
            type: string
            nullable: true
            unique: true
```

config.yml

```
sylius_resource:
    resources:
        app.product_image:
            classes:
                model: AppBundle\Entity\ProductImage
                form: AppBundle\Form\Type\ProductImageType
            translation:
                classes:
                    model: AppBundle\Entity\ProductImageTranslation
                    form: AppBundle\Form\Type\ProductImageTranslationType
```

Result is the following error:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t1.type AS type_2, t1.path AS path_3, t1.id AS id_4, t1.owner_id AS owner_id_5 FROM sylius_product_image t1 WHERE t0.owner_id = ?' with params [22]:

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't0.owner_id' in 'where clause'
```

It seems to me, that the error occurs because of missing joined translation table.

Comment: Did you also generated and applied migration / and or updated schema?
`php bin/console doctrine:migration:diff` or `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update`

Comment: Yes, and I can see the resulting translation table: `app_product_image_translation`

Answer (score 1):

You need to also override default ProductImage in sylius_core (http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/customization/model.html)

config.yml:

```
sylius_resource:
    resources:
        app.product_image:
            classes:
                model: AppBundle\Entity\ProductImage
            translation:
                classes:
                    model: AppBundle\Entity\ProductImageTranslation

sylius_core:
    resources:
        product_image:
            classes:
                model: AppBundle\Entity\ProductImage
```

And then follow translatable guide: http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/cookbook/custom-translatable-model.html

If you follow all the guidelines, you will be able to generate new entities BUT you will get the following:

```
The association AppBundle\Entity\ProductImageTranslation#translatable refers to the inverse side field AppBundle\Entity\ProductImage#translations which does not exist.
```

You can make it work by editing `Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\DependencyInjection\Configuration`
and adding a 'translation' node under 'product_image' which is obviously not a thing to do...

Maybe if a sylius core member could give us a clue...

Comment: Thx for your reply. No that error is gone. I added the translation to the form an it appears in the admin.  


But new error came up while saving it.. -.-

_CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: "Call to a member function setLocale() on array" at /var/www/dev/vendor/sylius/sylius/src/Sylius/Bundle/ResourceBundle/Form/Type/ResourceTranslationsType.php line 63_

I checked the docs again but still can't find the problem.

Comment: I encountered the same "Call to a member function setLocale() on array" at /var/www/dev/vendor/sylius/sylius/src/Sylius/Bundle/ResourceBundle/Form/Type/ResourceTranslationsType.php" So for anybody who has that issue I had to remove the method:

"configureOptions" from the translation type form.

Answer (score 0):

The same error here, after a lot of hours I found the problem.

In the sylius_resource.resources declaration you must use "sylius.product_image" instead of "app.product_image".

Before:

```
sylius_resource:
    resources:
        app.product_image:
            classes:
                model: AppBundle\Entity\ProductImage
           translation:
                classes:
                    model: AppBundle\Entity\ProductImageTranslation
```

After:

```
sylius_resource:
    resources:
        sylius.product_image:
            classes:
                model: AppBundle\Entity\ProductImage
            translation:
                classes:
                    model: AppBundle\Entity\ProductImageTranslation
sylius_core:
    resources:
        product_image:
            classes:
                model: AppBundle\Entity\ProductImage
```

When you use app.product_image you are creating a new resource, you aren't modifying the ProductImage original resource, because this the $translations property is not added in the driver configuration automatically.